# How to make echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value in Java

Tags: java, linux

I have a board that is not raspberry pi (it is olinuxino) with debian 7. I found two libs for working with GPIO in java (Pi4j and DIO), but they can be used only on raspberry. I need only to send one byte to certain linux file. I tried:

```
File file=new File("/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value");
FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file);
byte[] bytes={1};
fos.write(bytes);//here exception
```

but I get java.io.IOException: Invalid argument.

How to do it? Is it possible?

P.S. full exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument.
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:305)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)
```

Comment: is this correct file name `/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value`? looks like directory.

Comment: @YoungHobbit Yes, everything is correct. The same path I used in bash echo 1... and everything works.

Comment: What does the IOException message say?

Comment: @El Guapo I updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. This is working. You need to write character value `1` into the file. Provide the value in single quotes. Other wise it will write the ASCII value 1 which is `start of heading`.

```
byte bytes='1';
fos.write(bytes);//here exception
fos.close();
```

**Note :** Always close the streams once your job is done.